# Display images from Firebase Realtime Database using recyclerView in Androidx

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

Guys i'm trying to build App like Instagram. I'm struck to fetch the data from the Firebase database and storage. The recyclerView is showing nothing. Help me out in fixing that.
all the data are store in Firebase database.[image]

Recyclerview Adapter page in the fragment page

```
ProgressBar proBar;
    private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener authStateListener;
    Context context;


    String cuurentUser;
    FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
    FirebaseRecyclerAdapter adapter;
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    List<Post> postingList;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_reviews, container, false);

        PostAdapter postAdapter = new PostAdapter(context, postingList);

        recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recycView);
        proBar = view.findViewById(R.id.proBar);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
        linearLayoutManager.setReverseLayout(true);
        linearLayoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(postAdapter);
        postAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        cuurentUser = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();

        getDetails();
        return view;
    }




    private void getDetails() {

        Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                Query query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Posts").child(cuurentUser);

                FirebaseRecyclerOptions<Post> options = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Post>()
                        .setQuery(query, new SnapshotParser<Post>() {
                            @NonNull
                            @Override
                            public Post parseSnapshot(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {


                                return new Post(snapshot.child("id").getValue().toString(),
                                        snapshot.child("profileImg").getValue().toString(),
                                        snapshot.child("username").getValue().toString(),
                                        snapshot.child("postImg").getValue().toString(),
                                        snapshot.child("description").getValue().toString(),
                                        snapshot.child("time").getValue().toString(),
                                        snapshot.child("date").getValue().toString(),
                                        snapshot.child("title").getValue().toString()
                                );
                            }
                        })
                        .build();


                adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Post, PostViewHolder>(options) {
                    @NonNull
                    @Override
                    public PostViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
                        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                                .inflate(R.layout.post_item, parent, false);
                        //PostViewHolder viewHolder = new PostViewHolder(view);
                        return new PostViewHolder(view);
                    }

                    @Override
                    protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final PostViewHolder holder, final int position, @NonNull final Post model) {

                        // String uid = getRef(position).getKey();



                        holder.uname.setText(model.getUsername());
                        holder.descrip.setText(model.getDescription());
                        holder.ptime.setText(model.getTime());
                        holder.pdate.setText(model.getDate());
                        holder.ptitle.setText(model.getTitle());


                        Glide.with(getContext()).load(model.getProfileImg()).into(holder.profImg);


                        Glide.with(getContext()).load(model.getPostImg()).into(holder.postImage);

                        holder.linear.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View v) {
                                Toast.makeText(context,  String.valueOf(position), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        });


                    }
                };
                recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

            }


        }, 2000);

    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        if(postingList != null)
            adapter.startListening();

    }


    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        adapter.stopListening();
    }

    public static class PostViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView uname, fname, descrip, ptime, pdate, ptitle;
        CircleImageView profImg;
        ImageView postImage;

        View mview;
        LinearLayout linear;

        public PostViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            mview = itemView;
            linear = itemView.findViewById(R.id.linearRoot);
            uname = itemView.findViewById(R.id.username);
            fname = itemView.findViewById(R.id.fullname);
            descrip = itemView.findViewById(R.id.description);
            ptime = itemView.findViewById(R.id.ptime);
            pdate = itemView.findViewById(R.id.pdate);
            ptitle = itemView.findViewById(R.id.ptitle);
            profImg = itemView.findViewById(R.id.profImg);
            postImage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.postImg);
        }
    }
```

model page as Post.java

```
public class Post implements Parcelable {

    public Post() {

    }
    private String uid;
    private String postImg;
    private String description;
    private String username;
    private String date;
    private String time;
    private String profileImg;
    private String title;

    public Post(String uid, String postImg, String description, String username, String date, String time, String profileImg, String title) {
        this.uid = uid;
        this.postImg = postImg;
        this.description = description;
        this.username = username;
        this.date = date;
        this.time = time;
        this.profileImg = profileImg;
        this.title = title;
    }

    protected Post(Parcel in) {
        uid = in.readString();
        postImg = in.readString();
        description = in.readString();
        username = in.readString();
        date = in.readString();
        time = in.readString();
        profileImg = in.readString();
        title = in.readString();
    }

    public static final Creator<Post> CREATOR = new Creator<Post>() {
        @Override
        public Post createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new Post(in);
        }

        @Override
        public Post[] newArray(int size) {
            return new Post[size];
        }
    };

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getUid() {
        return uid;
    }

    public void setUid(String uid) {
        this.uid = uid;
    }

    public String getPostImg() {
        return postImg;
    }

    public void setPostImg(String postImg) {
        this.postImg = postImg;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(String date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    public String getTime() {
        return time;
    }

    public void setTime(String time) {
        this.time = time;
    }

    public String getProfileImg() {
        return profileImg;
    }

    public void setProfileImg(String profileImg) {
        this.profileImg = profileImg;
    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeString(uid);
        dest.writeString(postImg);
        dest.writeString(description);
        dest.writeString(username);
        dest.writeString(date);
        dest.writeString(time);
        dest.writeString(profileImg);
        dest.writeString(title);
    }
}
```

xml page with recyclerView

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".TabLayout.ReviewsFragment">

   <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:id="@+id/recycView"
       />

    <ProgressBar
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/proBar"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

Another xml page to show the details is post_item.xml

Comment: please try to add `adapter.startListening();` the line before `recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);` within your handler

Comment: i tried that. But it's still not working